# How to replace the place holder while customizing validation messages

Tags: jsf-2

i want to override the message for my h:message What i did i make message.properties file and add it in the faces-config.xml like this

```
<application>
     <message-bundle>
            pk.mazars.basitMahmood.MyMessage
  </message-bundle>
</application>
```

Here is the file

```
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE = {2}: ''{0}'' could not be understood as a date.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE_detail = Invalid date format.

javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM = Minimum length of ''{0}'' is required.
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {1}: Value is required
```

In my code i used something like this

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}"
             size="20" required="true" label="Username">                   
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="username" style="color:red" />
```

But i get something like this
[image]

I want instead of getting `{1}: value is required`. I get `username: Value is required`. How can i replace `{1}` with the value. I also tried `{0}` and '{2}'. But i am getting the same result?

Thanks

Comment: what do you see with javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0} Value is required ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0} Value is required
```

`{0} instead of {1}`

[Here a complete Reference to all available message that you can override in JSF 2.0.x](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/2.0.x/api/src/main/resources/javax/faces/Messages.properties)

try to restart the web server...

cause `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0} Value is required` should work